# Knp\Snappy\Pdf generateFromHTML not generating the PDF with correct filename

Tags: php, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I have PDF download functionality in my Laravel application.

It works perfectly when the PDF filename is English, the problem is with other languages.

```
$pdf = new Pdf();
...
$pdf->generateFromHtml(View::make('invoices.download'.$preferences->invoice_template, $data), $pdf_file_loc);
return Response::download($pdf_file_loc);
```

In the above code, `$pdf_file_loc` has a full path of PDF file as well as the PDF filename. Currently, for instance, when the filename is "Förderverein_für.pdf" (it is German), the real name of created PDF file is "Frderverein_fr.pdf".

In other words, the `generateFromHtml` function is not creating the PDF file with correct German filename.

But after that, as `$pdf_file_loc` is containing the correct German name, it is trying to download the "Förderverein_für.pdf" file which isn't exist (in the `return Response::download($pdf_file_loc)`).

So it is showing an error page when I try to download the PDF file

This is causing a serious problem in my live application as the PDF filename contains our customer's company name and it is often written by foreign languages (not English).

Comment: I thought if there can be a problem with PDF file's encoding, I tried to set the encoding option to utf8 but it doesn't give me effect.
$pdf->setOption('encoding', 'utf8');

Comment: Is the PDF dynamically generated? If so, the filename as presented to the user does not need to be the same as a file on disk. Indeed, there does not need to be a file on disk at all. Would you clarify how this works?

Comment: Thanks, halfer, your idea of different filename gave me the clue and I finally fixed my problem. I'm providing the details in answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `generateFromHtml` function is not creating the file with other languages (not English), I didn't include other languages in the filename but tried to reset the filename with other language while downloading the file.

So, now the `$pdf_file_loc` doesn't include other language and it is stored with only English in the app store but convert it to other language while downloading.

```
return Response::download($pdf_file_loc, $filename);
```

I don't think this is best answer but as long as the purpose is to get the PDF filename with other language, this solves my problem.